# Google Analytics API how do I query multiple URLs with googleapis package for node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I want to query a list of urls to get their page views in a single api call. My code for page views for the entire site is like so:

```
jwt.authorize((err, response) => {
    google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(
    {
      auth: jwt,
      ids: 'ga:SOMEID',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'today',
      metrics: 'ga:pageviews'
    },
    (err, result) => {
      console.log(err, result)
    }
  )
});
```

How would I query for a list of urls instead of the views for the entire website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dimension` query parameter to list page path dimension in your report. Also you can use the `filter` parameter to only include some specific page paths.
Check the Core Reporting V3 [Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) for more details